# Photodiode for PT2222

Tags: diodes, identification, infrared, remote-control

Recently I dropped my Bluetooth speaker remote and it stopped working. After testing it with remote control diagnostic tool (one of the cheap component testers from eBay that also decodes remote control signals) I noticed that the remote does not send any IR signals. After testing it with a scope I pinpointed the issue to the IR diode (It was cracked inside). Sadly, there is not much documentation for the device therefore all I have is IC code. After reviewing the datasheet:
https://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/35109/PTC/PT2221-001/211/4/PT2221-001.html
I can confirm that the circuit on page 4 represents the circuit in my remote (current limiting resistor in series with IR diode and BJT. I believe the resistor in my remote is also 1 Ohm this can be changed depending on the replacement diode and its voltage/current characteristic. One thing I am unsure of is the wavelength of the diode. Perhaps someone could advise on what wavelength it would most likely operate at. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two effects determine wavelength sensitivity of the infra-red remote receiver.

- Bandgap of silicon photodiode
- Optical filter of the encapsulating resin

Short-wavelength light is very effectively filtered out by the plastic, while infra-red light is passed through to the photodetector with little attenuation. The 3-pin receiver chip will appear glossy black.
Wavelength sensitivity of a common receiver chip from a Vishay TSOP12xx data sheet:
[image: Vishay IR remote receiver wavelength sensitivity]

 Any IR LED having about 900nm peak wavelength should work. A wavelength less than 850 nm is too close to red. You should choose one whose **Absolute maximum** current is about one amp (1A) if you use a 1-ohm series resistor from a 3V battery. Since this will be a pulsed current, the average current will be lower.

---

For example, an infrared LED might allow a *surge current* of 1.5A lasting only 100 microseconds,. but maximum *average current* of 0.1A is allowed. This kind of spec suggests that heating causes damage, and is the likely cause of your diode failing.
In-between 0.1A and 1.5A, **time and current** combine, so that the chip doesn't overheat:
[image: current vs. pulse duration graph]

 Since most remotes operate at about 40 kHz, pulse duration is about 0.0125 milliseconds. Furthermore, packets of between 10-20 pulses are transmitted, with a break in between, which further limits heating. And packets are sent only while you press a key.

 At the very least, ensure that the switching transistor that drives the LED is not shorted. And if you want to be conservative, increase the value of the 1-ohm series resistor that limits current, and point your remote more carefully at its intended target.